# Want to fetch data from 2 different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express, routes

What i want to do is on GET request i want to fetch data from 2 different tables

```
exports.user_blogs=async(req,res)=>{
    try{

        const blogs= await Blog.findAll({
            where:{
                userId:req.params.userId

            }
        })
        const bookmarks=await Bookmark.findAll({
            where:{
                UserId:req.params.userId

            }
        })

        res.send({
            bookmarks:bookmarks,
            blogs:blogs,
            msg:'blogs has been fetched succesfully for User'
        })


        }
        catch(err){
                return res.status(400).send({
                error:`an error occured while fetching blogs`
            })
        }

}
```

but GET request stops after executing ```Blog.findaAll`` and it throws an error.. What should i do

Comment: plz share stack trace of error ? I hope you mean `userId` instead of `UserId` in Bookmark query ?

Comment: sir thank you.. I figured out the error by stack trace.. thank you so much..issue solved :)

Comment: write `console.error(err)` inside `catch` block and run your code. You should see stack trace when it will break.

Comment: yes sir... I did the same and was able to find the error :) ..thanks for the suggestion..